# Trying to use EJS to dynamically render an edit form

Tags: forms, express, ejs

The problem seems to be with EJS.  I might be trying to do something EJS wasn't designed for.

I'm working on a web app that uses forms with a variable number of fields.  If a Mongo document I'm editing has only one field, I don't want to display input boxes for any additional fields.

I'm able to dynamically control how many fields are displayed when documents are edited but I'm not able to dynamically display the current value of the fields.

If I use the value tag like this:  `value=<%= document.field1 %>`, it works fine.  This, however, would have to be manually repeated for each field, including fields that won't be present.

What I want to do is something like this:  `value=<%= 'document.field' + (i+1) %>`.  This would ideally produce the same rendered HTML the code above does.  However, what I see is `'document.field1'` rather than the data I want to retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS is just a thin wrapper around JavaScript code. Anything you can write in JavaScript you can write in EJS, it'll be included in the compiled template without modification.

So to reference a field with a dynamic name you'd use `[]` just like you would in any other JavaScript code. Based on the code you provided it would be something like this:

```
value="<%= document['field' + (i + 1)] %>"
```

Comment: Thank you.  You helped me a great deal.